# Is it possible to add paragraph spacing inside of a textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea

Just wondering if anyone has any ways of adding paragraph spacing visuals to text inside a textarea via CSS, or even JS?

I'm aware of line-height but would like to add the impression of spacing before/after paragraphs themselves inside of a textarea, instead of having to hit enter twice inside the textarea to get a space between paragraphs.

Is this possible with a textarea alone or do I need to consider rich text editors, or maybe even writing a simple text editor myself with paragraph spacing? (I'd rather not go this route as I am merely after paragraph spacing, not all the additional formatting options that comes with text editors)

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Without the `line-spacing` property you cannot add space between paragraphs in a `textarea` without altering the value of the area. This is not something that JavaScript or CSS selectors can do.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it should be possible with JavaScript by replacing the value of the textarea while listening for [keyboard event values](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/), specifically for the Enter key.

You store the value in a variable, and whenever a user hits enter (its event value is `13`), it takes that text and adds a new line to the end. Now that becomes the value stored in the variable, and a new line is added the next time the user hits enter, and so on.

Here's an easy implementation if you're already using jQuery:

```
$('#my-text').keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which === 13) {
    var text = $('#my-text').val();
    $('#my-text').val(text + '\n');
  }
});
```

`e` is the keyboard event passed in as a parameter, and when that happens to be an enter key, the code stores the text value and then replaces the value of the textarea with that value plus a new line.

Here's a demo on codepen:
http://codepen.io/denmch/pen/qNyjZE

Comment: It's not ok. The user can hit <enter> while having the cursor/caret in the middle of the text.

Comment: Hi, Pablo. This was a simple proof of concept demo. You could easily code something more robust on the same principles, accounting for cursor placement.